# How to draw equally distanced normal lines between two multi-segmented Cubic Bézier splines?

Tags: javascript, bezier, spline, normals, cubic-bezier

[image]

Hello,

I have two multi-segmented cubic Bézier splines S and S′ that cut off by lines A and B (img.1). The distance between red dots it's their cubic Bézier curves. My question is how to split each of these two splines (S and S′) to equal segments and draw <s>normal</s> lines between those segments points (img.2).

Any ideas? Thankful in advance for any help.

Comment: The line you draw between points that split the two curves into equal segments are not necessarily "normal" to the curves.

Comment: @fang Yes, I agree with your comment. Normal lines are not a necessary condition in this situation. Do you have any ideas in which way to dig?

Comment: Do the measurements have to be exact, or does it just have to "look right"?

Comment: @psmears It just needs to be present the ability to regulate fractions after the decimal point. Still, you got the point, yes it just has to "look right".